# Pandas merge is giving different answers with index merge and column merge

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have three DataFrames for which I am trying to merge and output the result. The common column in each DataFrame I am trying to merge on is `COUNTRY`.

Case1:
Before merging the three DataFrames I have set the index of each DataFrame to `COUNTRY` and did

`pd.merge(leftdf,rightdf,left_index=True,right_index=True,how="inner")`

I am getting the required answer. But when I am not setting the indices of each DataFrame to `Country`, leaving them as columns, and performing the merge

`pd.merge(leftdf,rightdf,on="Country",how="inner")`

the resultant DataFrame is reduced in size. I am loosing some rows. Why is this happening? I do not understand.

Comment: Hi would you be able to give an example as to what you are seeing and what is the expected out put? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: These three are quite large data frames.my expected output is to get a data frame with the countries common in all initial data frames.                                                         but some of the countries are missing when i use the merge on columns rather than merge on indices.

Comment: @sajeera Can you narrow down your problem to a tiny version of it that demonstrates your problem? Perhaps two dataframes with 3 or 4 rows each, where the first merge works as expected and the second one doesn't? Otherwise it's really hard to guess what is going wrong with your merge...

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a moment to read about how to post pandas questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples